# Trimming bash string for aws ecr repo

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I need to trim a single `"` from a bash string both from starting and ending. I tried many things, but still didn't get the output.

Note: I tried `$a{// \"}`, but it didn't work.

The following code is what I have tried:

```
repoUri=$(aws ecr create-repository --repository-name $reponame | jq ".repository.repositoryUri")
$repoUri
```

Comment: my output is "********.ecr.**/repo"

Comment: but i need ********.ecr.**/repo

Comment: check the `-r`/`--raw-output` option of `jq`

Comment: You have your replacement backwards, it's `${a/old/replacement}`

Comment: And the `{` has to go before the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `-r` jq option for "raw output" to suppress the double quotes:

```
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "$reponame" \
    | jq -r '.repository.repositoryUri'
```

But you don't actually need jq at all – you can use the `--query` option in the request, and suppress the double quotes with `--output text`:

```
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "$reponame" \
    --query 'repository.repositoryUri' --output text
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Benjamin W.